# Create dynamic horizontal linearlayout inside a vertical linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some circular image and textview inside horizontal linear layout. My horizontal linear layout is inside of vertical linear layout. I tried to add the horizontal layout inside of the vertical layout.But it gives fatalexception.I am new to android layout.So dont have any idea of what to do next.Thank you in advance.

**Subcription.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscription);
        createpage();
    }
    public void  createpage()
    {
        LinearLayout LLV=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LLV);
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            LinearLayout LLH=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LLH);
            LLH.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            CircleImageView circleImageView2=(CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.circleimage2);
            TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            //Log.d("idname",findViewById(R.id.circleimage2).toString());

            circleImageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
            textView.setText("DIPTO");
            LLH.addView(circleImageView2);
            LLH.addView(textView);
            LLV.addView(LLH);
        }

    }
```

**activity_subscription.xml**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="543dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LLV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LLH"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/circleimage2"
                    android:layout_width="96dp"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="#00000000"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the > child's parent first.

Comment: It's already in XML then why are you doing that same thing??? Instead of this just add in _ScrollView_

Comment: In the xml there is only one horizontal linear layout. But I want to create 6 horizontal linear layout inside of the vertical linearlayout dynamically.

Comment: Then Why don't you go with _RecyclerView_?

Comment: I am new to android .Didn't have the idea of Recyclerview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `LinearLayout LLH` has already in xml & has parent. It you want to add dynamic layout to LLV then replace this

```
LinearLayout LLH=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LLH);
        LLH.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        CircleImageView circleImageView2=(CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.circleimage2);
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        //Log.d("idname",findViewById(R.id.circleimage2).toString());

        circleImageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
        textView.setText("DIPTO");
        LLH.addView(circleImageView2);
        LLH.addView(textView);
        LLV.addView(LLH);
```

with this

```
LinearLayout LLH= new LinearLayout(this);
        LLH.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        CircleImageView circleImageView2=new CircleImageView(this);
        TextView textView=new TextView(this);
        //Log.d("idname",findViewById(R.id.circleimage2).toString());

        circleImageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
        textView.setText("DIPTO");
        LLH.addView(circleImageView2);
        LLH.addView(textView);
        LLV.addView(LLH);
```

Comment: I am trying your approach.Thank you for your response.

Comment: & If you have array of data than use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). It is a good & easy approach.